# RDataFrame to Dataset

Tags: data, dataset, rlink

Is there an easy way to convert an RDataFrame object to a Mathematica Dataset?

For example I have an R function which returns

```
RDataFrame[RNames["date", "price"], RData[RObject[{16770, 16771, 16772, 
16773, 16776, 16777, 16778, 16779, 16780, 16783, 16784, 16785, 16786, 16787,
16790, 16791, 16792, 16793, 16794, 16797, 16798, 16799, 16800}, 
RAttributes["class" :> {"Date"}]], {2.4745, 2.5068, 2.6488, 2.6125, 2.572, 
2.5712, 2.5945, 2.622, 2.545, 2.582, 2.6293, 2.6618, 2.5888, 2.588, 2.5815, 
2.6178, 2.6325, 2.606, 2.6025, 2.5908, 2.6604, 2.6423, 2.619}], RRowNames[1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
23]]
```

Can this be converted to a Dataset easily? How can the R dates be converted into Mathematica Dates?

Comment: It is totally possible, just needs a little bit of work. I'm gonna try...

Comment: For those interested, the implementation of `RDataFrame` is really short  and simple and available at `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Links", "RLink", "Kernel", "DataTypes", "Base.m"}]`, which you can just `SystemOpen` (or view in your editor of choice). The general way to register your own data type wrappers is described in detail in the relevant part of the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/RLink/tutorial/DataTypes.html) (the section called "Extending RLink Type System by Defining Your Own Data Types").

Comment: What are the dates you are expecting from that date specification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be enough to convert date columns and make a `Dataset`:

```
FromRForm[
 RDataFrame[RNames[names__], RData[data__], RRowNames[rownames__]]] :=
  Dataset@AssociationThread[{rownames} -> Map[AssociationThread[{names} -> #] &, 
   Transpose[FromRForm /@ {data}]]]
FromRForm[RObject[x_, RAttributes[attrs__]]] /; 
  MemberQ[Lookup[{attrs}, "class"], "Date"] := 
   DatePlus[DateObject[{1970, 1, 1}], #] & /@ x
FromRForm[x_List] := x
```

Comment: Good. Using `FromRForm` was my second idea, but I didn't want to fiddle with it. (+1)

Comment: I would not add `DownValues` to `FromRForm`. One can instead unregister the `RDataFrame` type and register one's own for the `"data.frame"` type. How to do this is described in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/RLink/tutorial/DataTypes.html). Otherwise, I'd upvote this answer.

Comment: @swish. Thanks, this works

Answer (score 4):

*Update*: Added date conversion from @swish post.

You may use the set of *`RGet*`* functions.  Their existence is confirmed in the [R Data Types in RLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/RLink/tutorial/DataTypes.html) tutorial but they do not have their own documentation page.  Also `RGetAttributes` seems not to be working so a small bit of code was used to get these. Hopefully WRI will do some additional documentation work on RLink when they possibly revisit it in Mma 11.3.

```
Needs["RLink`"]
InstallR[]
```

`fromRObject` is a lazy attempt to convert an RObject into something the Wolfram Language functions can directly use. There maybe something that already does this in RLink but in my quick scan of the tutorials and guides I did not find it.

```
ClearAll[fromRObject];
fromRObject[o_RObject] :=
 Module[{class = First["class" /. List @@ FirstCase[o, _RAttributes]],
   convert},
  convert = Switch[class,
    "Date", DatePlus[DateObject@{1970, 1, 1}, {#, "Day"}] &,
    (* add other cases here *)
    _, Identity];
  convert /@ First@o
  ]
fromRObject[list_List] := list
```

`fromRDataFrameToDataset` uses the *`RGet*`* functions to extract the information from `RDataFrame`.

```
ClearAll[fromRDataFrameToDataset];
fromRDataFrameToDataset[df_RDataFrame] :=
 Module[{colNames, rowNames, data},
  {colNames, rowNames, data} = 
   Through@{RGetNames, RGetRowNames, Map[fromRObject]@*RGetData}@df;
  Dataset@
   AssociationThread[rowNames, 
    AssociationThread[colNames, #] & /@ Transpose@data]
  ]
```

With

```
rdf = 
RDataFrame[RNames["date", "price"], RData[RObject[{16770, 16771, 16772, 
16773, 16776, 16777, 16778, 16779, 16780, 16783, 16784, 16785, 16786, 16787,
16790, 16791, 16792, 16793, 16794, 16797, 16798, 16799, 16800}, 
RAttributes["class" :> {"Date"}]], {2.4745, 2.5068, 2.6488, 2.6125, 2.572, 
2.5712, 2.5945, 2.622, 2.545, 2.582, 2.6293, 2.6618, 2.5888, 2.588, 2.5815, 
2.6178, 2.6325, 2.606, 2.6025, 2.5908, 2.6604, 2.6423, 2.619}], RRowNames[1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
23]];
```

Then

```
fromRDataFrameToDataset[rdf]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

I think something like this should be incorporated into `` RLink` ``. There is a method for `TableForm`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Edmund. As @swish pointed out the dates are converted using DatePlus[DateObject[{1970, 1, 1}]. I'm not really sure how to modify fromRObject to convert the dates accordingly. From what I can tell this solution is fast (3 times faster than the other solutions)

Comment: @mark Curious, if it is 3x as fast why wasn't it picked as the answer?

Comment: "Curious, if it is 3x as fast why wasn't it picked as the answer?" -- OP's post says "Can this be converted to a Dataset easily?", and your answer is not on the easy or simple side. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way.

1. In R export the data frame to CSV.
2. In Mathematica read the CSV file with `SemanticImport`.

Here is code showing that.

#### Make a data frame

```
Needs["RLink`"]
InstallR[]

REvaluate["A <- c('a','b','a','b','c')"];
REvaluate["B <- c(123,343,343,34,34)"];
REvaluate[
  "begindate <- as.Date(c('2014-01-01', '2014-01-03', '2014-01-03', '2014-01-02', '2014-01-02'))"];
REvaluate[
  "enddate <- as.Date(c('2014-01-04', '2014-01-05', '2014-01-06', '2014-01-04', '2014-01-06'))"];
REvaluate[
  "df <- data.frame(A, B, begindate, enddate, stringsAsFactors=F)"];

REvaluate["df"]

(* RDataFrame[RNames["A", "B", "begindate", "enddate"], 
 RData[{"a", "b", "a", "b", "c"}, {123., 343., 343., 34., 34.}, 
  RObject[{16071., 16073., 16073., 16072., 16072.}, 
   RAttributes["class" :> {"Date"}]], 
  RObject[{16074., 16075., 16076., 16074., 16076.}, 
   RAttributes["class" :> {"Date"}]]], RRowNames[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]] *)
```

#### Export to CSV file

```
REvaluate["write.csv(x=df,file='~/MathFiles/Questions/df.csv',row.names=F)"]
```

#### Semantic import

```
SemanticImport["~/MathFiles/Questions/df.csv"]
```

[image]